# Power Query: How do I add a column with values combined from two other columns whose column headers are dynamic?

Tags: powerquery

I'm able to do the basic operation of creating the new column, but since the source columns have dynamic headers, I run into an error as soon as the header changes. The headers for the source columns are derived from defined names Variable1 and Variable2 as below.

Column 1 Header = Variable1&" Column Name"

Column 2 Header = Variable2&" Column Name"

I need to add a new column that calculates the difference between Column 1 and Column 2.
I tried some approaches but didn't really work out. I was hoping that the below code would work, but it spits an error message.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Prior Step", "New Column Name", each [Variable1&" Column Name"]-[Variable2&" Column Name"])
```

How do I get it to work without an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table.ColumnNames(Source){0} is the name of the 1st column of table Source

Table.ColumnNames(Source){1} is the name of the 2nd column of table Source

Record.Field(_,"xxx") is the contents of the current row in column named xxx

So to get difference between the first and second column in the current row, no matter their column names, use

```
Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){0})- Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){1})
```

If instead you know the names of the columns you want to use, and have the names in variables MyKnownName1 and MyKnownName2, then use

```
Record.Field(_,MyKnownName1)- Record.Field(_,MyKnownName2)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great now. Just to close the loop, below is the modified code.  =Table.AddColumn(#"Prior Step", "New Column Name", each Record.Field(_, Variable1&" Column Name") - Record.Field(_, Variable2&" Column Name"))